# Is this a bug with fancyvrb, fancyhdr and fontspec?

Tags: luatex, fontspec, fancyhdr, fancyvrb

Consider the following (hopefully minimal) non-working example and compile with `luatex` (TeXlive 2016):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{texgyrebonum-regular.otf}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot[C]{{\addfontfeature{Numbers = SlashedZero}0}}
\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}[frame = single]
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
  Test
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

One can see this in the footer of the first page:

[image]

There is obviously something wrong. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This doesn't seem to happen with TeXlive 2015; I get a slashed zero as the footer.

Comment: It happens for me on texlive 2015 too. Don't use \addfontfeature in this place. Define a new font family/face, e.g. `\newfontfamily\footerfont{texgyrebonum-regular.otf}[Numbers = SlashedZero]` and use this in the footer.

Comment: Somehow the font assignment happens at a wrong time and the code is read verbatim.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Is this mandatory or should I consider it a bug of `fontspec` and report it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a fontspec/lua problem in the distribution.
The file .../texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.lua on line 29/30 has the following code

```
local function tempswatrue()  tex.sprint([[\FontspecSetCheckBoolTrue ]]) end
local function tempswafalse() tex.sprint([[\FontspecSetCheckBoolFalse]]) end
```

This code, however uses the catcodes that are current instead of the standard LaTeX catcodes. These two lines should be replaced by

```
local latex = luatexbase.registernumber("catcodetable@latex")
local function tempswatrue()  tex.sprint(latex,[[\FontspecSetCheckBoolTrue ]]) end
local function tempswafalse() tex.sprint(latex,[[\FontspecSetCheckBoolFalse]]) end
```

which uses the standard LaTeX code. Of course this should be changed in the official distribution.

See https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/230.

Comment: Could you place the necessary details of the external link in this post? That would make the post self-contained rather than suggesting click-throughs to some *other* site to see what the issue is.